# How can I view non-ascii characters in ascii editor

Tags: ascii, extended-ascii

I'm very new to character encoding, I never really stopped to analyze how it works. My question is as follows, I have a text editor, for example the windows notepad, when I write a file in ascii encoding in which there is in this file a non-ascii character, such as ®, how is it possible for me to visualize this character, without breaking anything, if the file is encoded in ASCII ? Or simply those editors that use ASCII, actually use Extended ASCII?

Comment: Notepad by default uses the [Windows-1252 aka CP-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) character set, commonly mislabeled ANSI. There is no single "Extended ASCII" encoding, be careful with info that suggests this.

Comment: Notepad (on modern versions of Windows, at least) supports other encodings; File -> Save As will show you an "Encoding" dropdown. The Unicode encodings (UTF-8 being the default) support "all" characters, or at least all characters defined in Unicode, which is almost every character invented since the dawn of time.

Comment: Thanks, that was my question, taking advantage of your comment, by default I know that linux uses utf-8, but when I save a text file, using nano, by default it seems to use ascii, when I do a $ file test .txt, it gives the output stating that the file is ascii, but how can I visualize that same character ® in nano, if it says it is ascii ? @Blend3rman

Comment: That's more of a usage question that you might take to the Unix or Ubuntu stack sites. On my Ubuntu 20.04 system, using nano 4.8, saving a file with just a single ® in it produces a UTF-8 file (as reported by `file` 5.38). If you have a file in a "wrong" encoding you can use `recode` to change it (`recode ..ascii test.txt` gives `(R)`, since the character isn't supported in ASCII). Note that `file` uses heuristics and doesn't necessarily always get it right.